# Log failure transaction details after rollback

Tags: java, spring-boot, transactions, aop

I'm working on reverting some transactions been commit to the MySQL DB and run several methods and add failure transaction logs to the database after an exception happen.

I tried several methods, but none is working.
I'm using @Transactional, then nothing will commit to the database after an exception happen(even failure transaction logs)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Saving logs to the same data store transactionally seems like a questionable design in the first place.

Comment: What code have you used so far? From here on we can help you.

Comment: Please kindly learn how to ask questions, especially what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. Thank you very much.

Comment: @chrylis How can I store data about the failed transaction.

Comment: @RemcoBuddelmeijer I am searching for the best way of doing this using spring boot framework.

Action: Do some transactions(set of methods and database calls)

If any of the above method or any database call return exception.
Revert all database transactions.
Call set of methods.
Save data about this failed transaction.